# C++ how to return heap allocated c string without worrying about freeing it after it's been used?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

```
char *getPtrA()
{

   char *temp = (char*) malloc(len);
   
   strcpy(temp, "something");
   std::shared_ptr<std::string> var1 = std::make_shared<std::string>();
   var1->assign(temp);
   free(temp);

   return var1->c_str();

}

int main()
{
      char *mypointer = getPtrA();
      
      printf(stderrr, "content of ptrA = %s\n", mypointer);
}
```

Does the above code make sense?  What I am trying to do is to let the c string allocated from the heap to be freed within the GetPtrA function but the memory from the var1 becomes auto managed once exit without causing mem leaks.

Not sure if there is elegant way to do it or not.  What I am trying to do actually is not to worry about freeing the "temp" by the caller after it's done with it.

Thanks for any tips.

Tried using assign to a shared_ptr. Not sure if it works.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it that way? Simply return the `str::string` variable,  and use `c_str()` to interface with functions that want a `char` pointers.

Comment: Prefer to use `new/delete` versus `malloc/free`.  The operator `new` calls constructors and `malloc` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the above code make sense?

No. Once `var1` goes out of scope, the destructor of `shared_ptr` will realize that it is the only owner of the `std::string` and therefore call its destructor. Which in turn will destroy the memory being pointed to by the pointer you returned.

Also, you broke const-correctness, since `c_str()` returns a `char const*`, not a `char*`.

> What I am trying to do actually is not to worry about freeing the "temp" by the caller after it's done with it.

Then return a `std::string`. There is no way to return a `char*` *by itself* that will magically disappear once "the caller" is "done with it".

You have to use a real object, with a real constructor and destructor that really manages the lifetime of the string. If you want to "not worry," you have to stop returning raw pointers to things.

Comment: The problem is that I am refactoring old code where the caller/client side expects a raw c string. Don't know how to work around it.

Comment: @YangX: How did it work before without leaking memory? Replicate that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the operations of creation and deletion inside a class with a constructor and destructor.  Be careful!  There are lots of memory gotchas.  You'll be learning those while you are learning C++.  Also, note, that there are a lot of predefined classes that you can take advantage of as well: string is one of them.  Minimize reinventing the wheel.